Android 14 - App Hangs When Presenting Notification Permission Request
I am developing an Android app, and I'm facing an issue that seems related to Android 14 (API level 34). During the first app launch, I am presenting a notification permission request (POST_NOTIFICATIONS). However, when this request is triggered and the user interacts with it(either allowing or denying it), my app appears to hang on the splash it. If I put the app in background and return to it, the login page appears.
Here is my relevant code which is called in onCreate() function of LoginActivity
if (isFirstRun) {
   setupPushNotificationsChannel()

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    // Check notifications permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this@LoginActivity,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
    ) {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
            REQUEST_POST_NOTIFICATION_CODE_PERMISSION
        )
    }
}
// Flip firstRun
preferences.edit().putBoolean(FIRST_RUN_KEY, false).apply()
}


private fun setupPushNotificationsChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Create channel to show notifications.
        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
        )
    }

}


Hi, were you able to resolve this?

Unfortunately no :( it still hangs on the splash screen, the only thing that lets me go further is closing the app and starting it again.

Override the fun onRequestPermissionsResult() to add logic to navigate to login screen based on the user interaction.
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_POST_NOTIFICATION_CODE_PERMISSION && grantResults == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            // Load login page
 }


I am already on the Login page, the code I provided is called in onCreate() of Login Activity

In my opinion, Vishnu S Dharan's suggestion is correct, and I suggest to change the code as follows
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    // Check notifications permission
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this@LoginActivity,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
    ) {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS),
            REQUEST_POST_NOTIFICATION_CODE_PERMISSION
        )
    }
    else
    {
        if (isFirstRun) {
           setupPushNotificationsChannel()
           // Flip firstRun
           preferences.edit().putBoolean(FIRST_RUN_KEY, false).apply()
        }   
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_POST_NOTIFICATION_CODE_PERMISSION && grantResults == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            // 
           if (isFirstRun) {
              setupPushNotificationsChannel()
              // Flip firstRun
              preferences.edit().putBoolean(FIRST_RUN_KEY, false).apply()
           }
        }   
 }

private fun setupPushNotificationsChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Create channel to show notifications.
        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
        )
    }

}

